# Cache method response instead of method execution spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I am new to spring and was working with caches.While working I found out that spring caches method execution.Can spring cache the response of the methods?For instance I add an item to a cache and if I request the same item,the cache is hit.
Right now tow different cache entries are made as two different methods are executed.Sorry if the question is bad but I would like to know about this.Thanks a lot.
Here are the methods

Save method:

```
@RequestMapping("/addnew/{Id}/{IdString}/{localId}/{pid}")
    @ResponseBody
    @CacheEvict(value = "LocalCache",allEntries = true,beforeInvocation = true)
    @Cacheable("LocalCache")
    public void addId(@PathVariable String Id, @PathVariable String IdString, @PathVariable String local, @PathVariable String pid) {

        Model test = new Model();

       test.setId(Id);
        test.setIdString(IdString);

        test.setLocal(local);

        test.setPid(pid);
        IdService.save(test);

    }
```

Get method:

```
@Query("Select IdAttributes from Model IdAttributes where IdAttributes.Id= :Id")
    @Cacheable("LocalCache")
    List < Model > getIdAttributesForMoID(@Param("Id") String Id);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what Spring Caching more or less does. Have your read [§31. Caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html)? Which specific difficulties do you have?

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial might help.

Comment: I was hoping to cache the response of the add method and when I try to fetch the same response,I should be able to hit the cache.Right now the method execution is being cached.

Comment: @Sr7 It would really help if you could provide some code you are using on your add method. Any change you are calling the cacheable method from the same class? In that case it wont work.

Comment: How do you know that you're fetching the same response? Would you first fetch the value, check it and see that it's in the cache and then return the value from the cache?

Comment: @Sr7 Yes, this is how it is supposed to work. Provided the implementation is correct. If you seek debugging help, you need to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It does not make much sense to just talk about how Spring Caching may or may not work.

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: Isn't it a bit useless to evict the cache there?

Comment: @Kayaman I'm saving the some value in my db and cache.When i fetch the same value the response is again stored in the cache.When i run the fetch method again , then only the cache is hit.

Comment: @Kayaman I think so too.

Comment: What I'm trying to know is can we cache response of methods instead of their execution.

Comment: Caching a void method is pretty much useless, also your setup is weird on each method call you are evicting the whole cache then why even bother with the cache. You are also using the same cache to cache different things again something you shouldn't do and finally (judging from the `@Query` on your method) is that you actually want to use the 2nd level cache of your JPA provider don't use spring Cache for that.

Comment: I don't know much about using second level cache.Currently I am using the guava cache as the cache provider.